# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Invalid array range: 1 to 1

Tags: java

Me arroja el error *"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Invalid array range: 1 to 1"* 
Esta es una clase que tengo creada y luego tengo un main donde llamo a la funcion **anadirAsignatura** , cuando añado una asignatura nueva perfecto, pero al añadir la segunda me falla arrojando el error de arriba.

```
public class Alumno {
private static int MAX = 5;


private String nom, apel, mat;
private double cal;
private int NumAsigs;
private String Asignaturas[] = {""};


private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private String matricula;
private double calificacion;
public int numAsigs;
private String asignaturas[] = {""};


//CONSTRUCTOR
public void Alummno() {
    nombre = "";
    apellidos = " ";
    matricula = "aa0000";
    calificacion = 0.0;
    numAsigs = 0;
}

public Alumno(String nom, String apel, String mat, double cal) {
    this.nombre = nom;
    this.apellidos = apel;
    this.matricula = mat;
    this.calificacion = cal;
    this.NumAsigs = numAsigs;
}


//CONSTRUCTOR
public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nombre = nom;
}

public String getApe() {
    return apellidos;
}

public void setApe(String apel) {
    this.apellidos = apel;
}

public String getMat() {
    return matricula;
}

public void setMat(String mat) {
    this.matricula = mat;
}

public double getCal() {
    return calificacion;
}

public void setCal(double cal) {
    this.calificacion = cal;
}

public String[] getAsignaturas() {
    return Asignaturas;
}

public void setAsignaturas(String[] asignaturas) {
    this.Asignaturas = asignaturas;
}

public int getNumAsigs() {
    return NumAsigs;
}

public void setNumAsigs(int numAsigs) {
    NumAsigs = numAsigs;
}

public void anadirAsignatura(String asig) {
        if (numAsigs < 5){
                asignaturas[numAsigs] = asig;
            //System.out.println(" => " + asignaturas[numAsigs].length());
                numAsigs++;

        }else System.out.println("El limite maximo es 5");
}

public void mostrarAsignaturas(){
    System.out.println(nombre+", "+apellidos+" esta matriculado en:");
    for (int i=0 ; i<numAsigs ; i++)
        System.out.println(" -"+asignaturas[i]);
}

public void mostrarAlumno(){
    System.out.println(apellidos+ ", " +nombre+ ". Matr: " +matricula+ "(" +calificacion+ ").");
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar como estas haciendo la llamada a `añadirasignatura`?

Comment: El array asignaturas tiene tamaño fijo de 1. Lo mismo para Asignaturas. Debes usar algun contenedor que se pueda redimensionar dinamicamente (ArrayList) y luego convertirlo a array.

Comment: Los arrays no crecen dinámicamente. En todo caso, al hacer una pregunta deberías indicar en qué línea te lanza la excepción y mostrar el stacktrace (aunque en este caso es un problema bastante simple y la verdad no es muy necesario).

Comment: Deberías eliminar los atributos duplicados: Asignaturas y asignaturas son dos arrays de String, seguramente uno de los dos sobre

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Perfecto solucionado con un ArrayList :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La **longitud** de los [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) **se establece desde el momento que se crean**, por lo que  esto:

```
private String asignaturas[] = {""};
```

le estas diciendo que es de longitud 1 y lo estas inicializando con un cadena vacia, de tal manera que lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente, ya que veo que lo estas limitando solo a 5 elementos:

```
private String asignaturas[] = {"","","","",""};
```

o esto:

```
private String asignaturas[] = new String[5];
```

Si no conoces el numero de elementos que va a tener el arreglo te recomiendo utilizar mejor un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) y despues convertirlo a Array

Answer (score 0):

Creando un ArrayList en vez de un Array de String es la solución, ya que el array que tenía no es dinámico.

***Actualización de los parámetros***

```
public ArrayList<String> asignaturas = new ArrayList<String>();


public ArrayList<String> Asignaturas = new ArrayList<String>();
```

***Getters And Setters***

```
public ArrayList<String> getAsignaturas() {
    return Asignaturas;
} 

public ArrayList<String> getAsignaturas() {
    return Asignaturas;
}

public void setAsignaturas(ArrayList<String> asignaturas) {
    Asignaturas = asignaturas;
}
```